How to avoid that a C++ Builder Android application quits when Camera In Use icon is shown in Android 12
I created a simple application for Android with C++ Builder (11.0).
The application simple shows the camera in full screen. It works as intended.
When the application runs there is an icon on he top left that pops up to let the user know that the camera es working "Camera in use" notification.
I am running it Emteria a industrial custom Android 12 in a rock 5B embedded device.
Emteria has a option that allows to launch an application on start. When I use that option to launnch my application all goes well until the "Camera in use" notification pops up. When that happens it sends my application to background.
I have not found a solution to this problem. Any hint?.
Thanks
----- log cat says it crashes and this the output---
--------- beginning of crash
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UiThreadHelper
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 1057
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:220)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3738)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3725)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.quickstep.SystemUiProxy.getRecentTasks(SystemUiProxy.java:763)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.quickstep.RecentTasksList.loadTasksInBackground(RecentTasksList.java:164)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.quickstep.RecentTasksList.lambda$getTaskKeys$1$RecentTasksList(RecentTasksList.java:90)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.quickstep.RecentTasksList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
09-10 07:03:04.836  1057  1115 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Also it has some references to  my app FoilCamera so I did a 'logcat | grep FoilCamera' and this is the output
9-10 07:02:57.187   521   684 W installd: Ignoring /data/data/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/lib with unexpected GID 0 instead of 10091
09-10 07:02:58.098   630   695 I SystemServerTimingAsync: InitThreadPoolExec:Update app-ops uidState in case package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera changed
09-10 07:02:58.098   630   695 D SystemServerInitThreadPool: Started executing Update app-ops uidState in case package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera changed
09-10 07:02:58.098   630   695 D SystemServerInitThreadPool: Finished executing Update app-ops uidState in case package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera changed
09-10 07:02:58.099   630   695 D SystemServerTimingAsync: InitThreadPoolExec:Update app-ops uidState in case package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera changed took to complete: 1ms
09-10 07:02:58.478   630   630 V StorageManagerService: Package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera does not have legacy storage
09-10 07:02:59.634   630   721 I WatchlistLoggingHandler: Skipping incremental path: com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:03.718   630   710 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera cmp=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} from uid 1000
09-10 07:03:03.745   630   710 V SplashScreenExceptionList: SplashScreen checking exception for package com.embarcadero.FoilCamera (target sdk:30) -> false
09-10 07:03:03.769   630   658 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2165:com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/u0a91 for pre-top-activity {com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
09-10 07:03:03.861  2165  2165 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.embarcadero.FoilCamera' set to: 'default'
09-10 07:03:03.861  2165  2165 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for com.embarcadero.FoilCamera: false
09-10 07:03:04.260  2165  2165 I dero.FoilCamera: type=1400 audit(0.0:269): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=280 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:04.260  2165  2165 I dero.FoilCamera: type=1400 audit(0.0:270): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=280 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:04.260  2165  2165 I dero.FoilCamera: type=1400 audit(0.0:271): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=280 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:04.260  2165  2165 I dero.FoilCamera: type=1400 audit(0.0:272): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=310 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1 app=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:04.260  2165  2165 I dero.FoilCamera: type=1400 audit(0.0:273): avc: denied { connectto } for path="/dev/socket/property_service" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1 app=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera
09-10 07:03:04.391   630   648 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: +671ms
09-10 07:03:04.428   630   694 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:04.528   630   652 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:04.528   630   652 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:04.528   630   652 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:04.532   630   651 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:06.306   509   509 I CameraService: CameraService::connect call (PID -1 "com.embarcadero.FoilCamera", camera ID 101) and Camera API version 1
09-10 07:03:06.307   509   509 I Camera2ClientBase: Camera 101: Opened. Client: com.embarcadero.FoilCamera (PID 2165, UID 10091)
09-10 07:03:06.463  2165  2165 D dero.FoilCamer: Successfully queried cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/code_cache
09-10 07:03:06.464  2165  2165 D RenderScript: Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/code_cache
09-10 07:03:10.834   630   648 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:10.842   630   651 V WindowManager: getPackagePerformanceMode -- ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} -- com.embarcadero.FoilCamera -- mode=0
09-10 07:03:10.929   630  1082 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{af5f8a8 u0 com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
09-10 07:03:10.929   630  1082 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'af5f8a8 com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
09-10 07:03:10.933   630  1174 I ActivityManager: Process com.embarcadero.FoilCamera (pid 2165) has died: fg  TOP
09-10 07:03:10.935   630  1174 W ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{740a8eb u0 com.embarcadero.FoilCamera/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity t27}: app died, no saved state
09-10 07:03:11.030   509   803 I Camera2ClientBase: Closed Camera 101. Client was: com.embarcadero.FoilCamera (PID 2165, UID 10091)
09-10 07:13:58.837   630  2461 I PackageDexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dexoptNeeded=1) on: /data/app/~~Zli59N_QsVlkGftLUYOtPg==/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera-1nRDfMEqcLjqB3WEiQ2c5Q==/base.apk pkg=com.embarcadero.FoilCamera isa=arm dexoptFlags=boot_complete,debuggable,public,enable_hidden_api_checks targetFilter=extract oatDir=null classLoaderContext=PCL[]{}
09-10 07:13:58.840   521   684 V installd: DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/~~Zli59N_QsVlkGftLUYOtPg==/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera-1nRDfMEqcLjqB3WEiQ2c5Q==/base.apk' ---
09-10 07:13:58.840   521   684 V installd: Running /apex/com.android.art/bin/dex2oat32 in=base.apk out=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@~~Zli59N_QsVlkGftLUYOtPg==@com.embarcadero.FoilCamera-1nRDfMEqcLjqB3WEiQ2c5Q==@base.apk@classes.dex
09-10 07:13:58.900  2464  2464 I dex2oat32: /apex/com.android.art/bin/dex2oat32 --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --classpath-dir=/data/app/~~Zli59N_QsVlkGftLUYOtPg==/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera-1nRDfMEqcLjqB3WEiQ2c5Q== --class-loader-context=PCL[]{} --compact-dex-level=none --compiler-filter=extract --compilation-reason=post-boot --max-image-block-size=524288 --resolve-startup-const-strings=true --debuggable --generate-mini-debug-info -j4
09-10 07:13:59.135   521   684 V installd: DexInv: --- END '/data/app/~~Zli59N_QsVlkGftLUYOtPg==/com.embarcadero.FoilCamera-1nRDfMEqcLjqB3WEiQ2c5Q==/base.apk' (success) ---
09-10 07:14:00.176   630  2461 I BackgroundDexOptService: Pinning optimized code {com.embarcadero.FoilCamera, com.embarcadero.AutoBoot}


What does the logcat say? Please add relevant logs to your question.

I am new to android development and I didn't know about logcat. Thanks for the tip. Logcat says this

I added the logcat information.  it seems that that "Camera in use" situation sends a message to my app that does not handle. The crash is not in my code but in the FMX code accordingly to the call stack.
